# Out of many tests, how many results could be false positives?

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value

I have a basic question about significance values and p-values.

Say I perform a test using 0.05 as the significance level. Using this p < 0.05, I obtain say 20 000 significant points. Is it valid to say that 5% of these points, so 1000 points, could be false positives?

P.s I am familiar with multiple test correction.

Comment: That doesn't sound right; if you have 20,000 "significant points", wouldn't each of these be subject to the 0.05 error? Though perhaps I misunderstand what the "significant points" are or how they might be obtained. If you meant to say that *if* you repeated the experiment 20,000 times, *and the null hypothesis really was correct*, you could expect to see ~1000 test statistics as or more extreme than the value observed in the one test (the one where you got a $p$ value < 0.05.)

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Eg, what are the "significant points" you are referring to?

Comment: @gung, My interpretation is that she's talking about the classification based on significance levels, like what is used in biostatistics. Say you run a blood test, and p-value is used to classify it as positive or negative for a disease.

Answer (score 2):

If the null hypothesis is true, then yes, you'd have 1,000 false positive. However, if your alternative is true, then no, moreover, you won't have any false positives.

Note, that your significance level $\alpha$ defines your Type I error rate. False positive rate needs one more input: the rate at which null is true. In your case, in order to tell what's the number false positives you need to know what is rate of true nulls. Let's say 10% of nulls are true, in this case you get: 20,000x0.05x0.1=100 false positives are expected.